# PHP, PDO & MYSQL : lastInsertId() returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am rather new at PDO-based MySQL and I'm running into a problem.

This is the method I'm executing :

```
public function insert( $table, $data )
{
  // utility functions to auto-format the statements
  $keys = $this->getKeys($data);
  $placeholders = $this->getPlaceholders($data);

  $q = "INSERT INTO $table ($keys) VALUES ($placeholders)";

  // this simply returns a new PDO object
  $dbh = $this->createSession();

  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);
  $stmt->execute( array_values($data) );

  return $dbh->lastInsertId();
}
```

After that, I run my method and store the returned value in a variable :

```
$new_user_id = $U->insert( $data );

var_dump($new_user_id);
```

And I get

```
NULL
```

**Note** the query is actually executed, and my data is correctly inserted into my table; no problem on that side. It seems it just can't grab the last insert ID as I ask for it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does the table have a primary key specified?

Comment: try passing a couple of optional attributes to the PDO constructor, or call `setAttribute` with `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

Comment: Does your table actually have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column?

Comment: c/p from the other reply : I checked the table settings and there is an 'id' field, type INT, with A_I checked, Primary Key.

Comment: I had the same issue when I've tried to run insert on SQLite database that was read only. Solution is to check `is_writable()` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reviewed the code again and I found that my value wasn't returned because of an intermediate method that wasn't passing the value correctly to the top-layer method.

Checking the value at the source shows no problem.

Thanks for the replies anyway.

Comment: Sadly, this was my issue, too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about any PDO-specific issues, but by default MySQL only returns an insert id if there's an auto_increment integer field in the database (generally but not necessarily the primary key).  If your table doesn't include this nothing is returned by $dbh->lastInsertId()

Comment: I checked the table settings and there is an 'id' field, type INT, with A_I checked, Primary. Still not sure it's not related to the DB though. But my config is pretty standard. Thanks for the reply.